# Tastypie returning 401 for POST with No-Op Authentication and Authorization

Tags: python, django, curl, tastypie

I'm trying to update some data from Tastypie with a POST request.

Here is a Curl command I have been trying:

```
curl -b cookies -v --data '{ "name" : "test" }' -H "X-CSRFToken: VhPYwzz4NJXnTPgkfSuSAQnN3HZ5AJj0" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schedules/
```

My resource looks like this:

```
class ScheduleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'schedules'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

And of course, I have a field in my model called name:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, default="Default Schedule")
```

Anyway, here's what goes down when I run the curl command:

```
> POST /api/v1/schedules/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: csrftoken=VhPYwzz4NJXnTPgkfSuSAQnN3HZ5AJj0; sessionid=q7vp6wkn2x5gy1036ibdnhbb0lexe3ac
> X-CSRFToken: VhPYwzz4NJXnTPgkfSuSAQnN3HZ5AJj0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 19
> 
* upload completely sent off: 19 out of 19 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
< Date: Sun, 15 Dec 2013 05:07:55 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

My assumption is that I'm not sending the correct data. Any thoughts?